# Kafka/flume reading transaction logs - real-time backup RDBMS

Tags: hadoop, flume, apache-kafka

Has anybody tried to use Kafka or Flume to tail/read RDBMS' transaction log and rewrite the data to Hadoop(e.g. HBase)? So you get to keep a near Real-Time back up from your RDBMS.

Looking for some experience sharing.

Comment: Linkedin themselves seem to use [Databus](https://github.com/linkedin/databus) for this purpose. See [this](http://www.slideshare.net/amywtang/icde-linkedin-finalwithauthors) interesting document.